# Did I get a dissociation malus?

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar

In the “community selection” drop down menu, my reputation on a particular meta site has been displayed 100 points smaller than the true amount for at least a week or so. The behaviour is consistent across different browsers on several devices, and independent of which SE site I use to view the drop-down. Note that this is not just a case of changes of reputation from the main site being out of sync with the meta site, as the reputation is displayed correctly in other places (e.g., in my profile on the meta site).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Oh my. Two duplicates, no less? My search skills must be failing.

Comment: All good, it's still not trivial to find. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you got a penalty of any sort, there's probably some bug or something.

I've been having a similar issue, only mine is a few hundred points:

[image]

The amount showed for meta is the amount of rep I had on 10/07/2018 (not sure if that is the same date across other accounts you can check by going to

[`https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation`](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation)

from what I could see, your account looks to be stuck since around then as well.